# SQL Optimization with Long IN Clause

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization, h2

I have a SQL like the following:

```
select a, b, c, d, e
from table
where a = a1
and b in (b1, b2, ..., b100000)
and c in (c1, c2, ..., c9999)
```

where the in-clause is very long, I think this can affect the performance, but not sure how to optimize it.

I already set up index for these 3 columns separately, and a is the most selective column. (btw, within a single SQL execution, will the db use index for a, then b, then c, or only use one index?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query cannot be optimized much, because the `IN` clauses boil down to `OR`, which is hard to tune.  But your insight to use an index was on the right track.  One approach here would be to create new tables `tableB` and `tableC` which contain all the whitelisted values which appear in your current `IN` clauses.  Then, replace the `IN` clauses with exists lookups to the `tableB` and `tableC` tables.

Define:

```
tableB:
  b
------
  b1
  b2
  ...
  b100000

tableC:
  c
------
  c1
  c2
  ...
  c9999
```

Then refactor your query to:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c, d, e
FROM yourTable a
WHERE a = a1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB tB WHERE tB.b = a.b) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableC tC WHERE tC.c = a.c);
```

The above query will benefit from putting an index on `tableB.b` and `tableC.c`.

Answer (score 0):

1. H2 can use only one index, but H2 will try to determine the most efficient index for your query. In few cases you may need to specify index hints.
2. You should avoid generation of long IN predicates, PostgreSQL-style quantified comparison predicate with array `A = ? AND B = ANY(?) AND C = ANY(?)` will be faster, see [Prepared Statements and IN(...)](https://h2database.com/html/performance.html#database_performance_tuning) section in documentation.